# Broadcast Reciever not working in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Activities:

- MainActivity   (Splash Screen)
- MainActivity2  (Login)
- SignupActivity (Signup)
- MainActivity3  (Registering details)
- ChatActivity   (Hide on quiting from here)

**Basically what i am trying to accomplish i i wanna hide my app after i do the initial signup part which will be handled uptill MainActivity3 and then when the user quits from the app the app icon should disappear and must only appear when called from dialer. My BroadcastReciever class never gets triggered,I am unable to figure out where i am going wrong Thanks in advance.**

BroadCastReceiver.class

```
package com.insignia.socialmediasim;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String ourCode = "**1234";
    String dialedNumber = getResultData();

    Log.d("triggered", "onReceive: "+dialedNumber);
    if ((dialedNumber.equals(ourCode))){
        // My app will bring up, so cancel the dialer broadcast
        setResultData(null);
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, com.insignia.socialmediasim.MainActivity.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        //Intent to launch MainActivity
        Intent intent_to_mainActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent_to_mainActivity);
    }
}}
```

ChatActivity.class, "This is the class in which i hide my app"

```
package com.insignia.socialmediasim;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Welcome Back to the adobe " + intent.getStringExtra("type"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(ChatActivity.this, com.insignia.socialmediasim.MainActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}}
```

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.insignia.socialmediasim">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/asd"
    android:label="@string/appnameda"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/asd"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".ChatActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity3" />
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Comment: in which class you are registering the broadcast receiver ?

Comment: It is registered in his manifest

Comment: It is recommended that register and unregister the broadcast programmatically in you activity.Try It

Comment: Thats not true.

Comment: @maryam thanks for replying i dont understand what you suggesting

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that register and unregister the broadcast programmatically in you activity.Try It.
this is a sample code for registering a broadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

You can check more information from this document: [broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#java)